# pdf byte serving slow in Internet explorer

Tags: internet, pdf, windows-explorer

When I try to access a large pdf file with Chrome with byte serving it steadily increases the size of the packets which are downloaded. Internet Explorer however stays with the 16KB packets. This causes that in Internet Explorer the file takes a lot longer as this causes that there are more than 5000 requests for files that are 100MB.

The fast web view option is enabled in my Adobe reader. Are there ways to change the packet size of the byte serving requests?

Comment: I have similar problems with IE, IE 9 and 10 usually hang when trying to open large pdf files. I think it just can’t handle so many requests.